# Integrate solr with NLP

Tags: search, solr, lucene, nlp

I am working on solr 4.8.1 version. I want to integrate solr with NLP in order to improve the search relevancy. I am unable to 
dig out a good tutorial that explains its configuration, its output, its benefit for Solr.

It tried this configuration:

```
<fieldType name="text_opennlp" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.OpenNLPTokenizerFactory"
      sentenceModel="opennlp/en-sent.bin"
      tokenizerModel="opennlp/en-token.bin"
    />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

But this is reporting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml]   fieldType "text_opennlp": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/tokenizer: Error loading class 'solr.OpenNLPTokenizerFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2899 patch mentioned in https://wiki.apache.org/solr/OpenNLP ?

It gives you the ability to only keep nouns and verbs.

Tip: check analysis for values in payload as they differ from Treebank example.

Comment: I had already seen the links, but cant find the jar file. I do not know how to add the patch file. Please help.

Comment: I am following these steps but still failing:
-> Downloaded solr-4.8.1 in /data/
-> cd /data/solr-4.8.1/;
-> Downloaded all four files from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2899; 
-> patch -p0 -i LUCENE-2899.patch
Getting the following error:


can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

Comment: Only use the latest patch.

Comment: I have already shared the links & steps That I am using. Is there any step this I am missing or any other link should I use ?. Please suggest.

Comment: You can check the patch line 5 and see what it tries to do. Then check if the operation is valid or if something needs to be changed.

Comment: The installation step at https://wiki.apache.org/solr/OpenNLP ran succesfully. I copied the following jars:

  solr/contrib/opennlp/lib/opennlp-maxent-3.0.3.jar
  solr/contrib/opennlp/lib/opennlp-tools-1.5.3.jar  in the lib directory. I made the changes in the schema.xml. Created opennlp dir in conf/ directory of the core & add en-* files in it. Still I am getting the following error:  

  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  solr.OpenNLPTokenizerFactory
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)

Comment: Did you copy solr-opennlp-4.8-SNAPSHOT.jar also?

Comment: yes after I trying this also, It is not working. Do I need to add more jar files as well ?

Comment: When I extracted lucene-analyzers-opennlp-4.8-SNAPSHOT.jar, I found that OpenNLPTokenizerFactory.class was missing into this. So I extracted this jar file & add this class solr/build/contrib/solr-opennlp/classes/java/org/apache/solr/analysis/OpenNLPTokenizerFactory.class & compiled it again. Still It is not working
...But how comes the OpenNLPTokenizerFactory.class missing when it was showing "Build Successfull" message at every step.
I even tried to find this class file in other two jar file, But it was not present.

Comment: You can always run the build.xml in solr/contrib/opennlp to make sure those classes are build.

Comment: Finally..it works @okke..thanks :). But how to test this analyzer. What input & output can be expected with this filter. Can I have better explanation like other filters discussed here https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters

Comment: I am not getting how to use this filter to improve the results ? Any updates ?

Comment: All you need to know is in the Wiki. Just test the different analyzers in analysis tool and watch the payload.